# How do I maintain equal distance between the 2 paths in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I am trying to keep the distance uniform between these 2 black lines. It is difficult to do manually.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "two black lines"? Do you mean that you want the stroke to maintain a consistent thickness?

Comment: yes, these black lines are the strokes, and the magenta color is just the "fill" not the actual stroke...

Answer (score 6):

I'd *guess* that the magenta path is actually a filled shape and not a stroked path. Construction would be easier, and more uniform, if everything was merely a stroked path.

You can then simply **stack strokes** in the **Appearance Panel**.

[image]

Making the underlying stroke thicker means it'll "poke out" of the sides. The thicker that bottom stroke is, the more you see of it..

And as *strokes*, everything is *always* equidistant from the spine (unless you use the Width Tool or set a stroke profile to change that).

If you then need *shapes* rather than strokes.. use `Object > Expand Appearance` and `Object > Expand` to create filled shapes from the stokes.

Comment: I would have to manually draw the airplane again, like it is shown in the image above...
I was hoping to get it done automatically somehow  ...
but i really appreciate your help in it .. :)

Comment: It honestly took me less than 15 seconds to draw the airplane as a stroke, as in my answer. Now, even if you aren't as familiar with the pen tool, the time it takes to draw the plane as a stroke will GREATLY outweigh any time you spend trying to get the pink shape to be uniform in width everywhere.